# Table Cell Renderer for enum

Tags: java, swing, enums, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have a table with two columns: attribute and value!
Attribute is an enum. Now I set a cell renderer for the enum class (should be displayed in lowercase).

**The problem is: the table never call the renderer!**

Enum (just an example):

```
public enum Attribute {
  BLUE,BLACK,RED;
}
```

Cell Renderer:

```
public class AttributeTableCellRenderer
    extends
        AbstractTableCellRenderer<Attribute> {  
    @Override
    protected Object getText(Attribute attribute) {
        System.out.println("call");
        if (null == attribute) {
            return null;
        }
        return attribute.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

Table (just an example):

```
// table model
Vector<Object> v;
Vector<String> header = new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList("attribute", "values"));
Vector<Vector<?>> data = new Vector<Vector<?>>();
// fill with data
for (final Attribute attribute : Attribute.values()) {
  v = new Vector<Object>();
  v.add(attribute);
  v.add("blah");
  data.add(v);
}
//table
TableModel tm = new DefaultTableModel(data, header);
JTable table = new JTable(tm);
table.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer());
table.setDefaultRenderer(Attribute.class, new AttributeTableCellRenderer());
// will work
//table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new AttributeTableCellRenderer());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to supply your own implementation of `AbstractTableModel` which implements `getColumnClass(int c)` and returns the class of the column.

Background: The table implementation doesn't try to map the value of each cell to a renderer but instead it asks the model for the class of the whole column.

Comment: Note you can simply override DefaultTableModel#getColumnClass() to keep the DefaultTableModel functionality.

Comment: Ah of couse. I forget to override these method. Sometimes you miss the obvious. :-)
Thanks!